# query the first element of a list in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my Elasticsearch index I have fields that are lists of strings:

"city" = ["Boston","NY","Chicago"]

I need to write a query that searches only the first element of the list.
I have accomplished this by adding a new field that contains only the first element.
"city_first"="Boston"

I like to avoid creating a new field.  Is there a way to write a query that searches only the 1st element of the list in Elasticsearch?